# How to capture the standard output of a script that depends on the user for some input?

Tags: bash, solaris, io-redirection

There is a script that requires me to enter the password before it continues:

```
bash-3.2$ ./script.sh <parameter_list>
Enter the password for the Database: 
..
..
```

I am interested in capturing the standard output of the script into a log file, while securely passing the password to the script.

I tried to pass the password into standard input as follows:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "<password>" > /secure/path/password.txt
bash-3.2$ ./script.sh <parameter_list> < /secure/path/password.txt
```

But this doesn't seem to work. If it did, I could simply use `tee` to redirect the output to a log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `expect`. This tool can interactively work with commands that need user input. Of course the major pitfall being that you have to know what to **expect**.

Example (borrowed from http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples/)

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 20

spawn "./hello.pl"

expect "hello"
send "no match : <$expect_out(buffer)> \n"
send "match :  <$expect_out(0,string)>\n"

interact
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
echo "password" | ./script.sh parameter_list ... > output.file
```

If that doesn' work, then answer this question: what mechanism does the script use to get the password from the user. If it's something like an ssh password, sending it via stdin won't work.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. It didn't work.. I connect to the Solaris box over SSH and then enter the password manually after running the script. So I guess there is no workaround in this case..

Comment: The best way is to use ssh keys, then you don't need to manually enter the password

Comment: I think this is a bit different, as after I connect to the box over SSH (PuTTY), I then manually enter the DB password after running the script. I think my solution lies in a Solaris equivalent of Ubuntu's `ttysnoop` command.

Comment: Maybe you want `expect`: programmatically enter the ssh password then switch to interactive mode to let you enter the db password.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your own script, may be you can send the interactive output to `stderr`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately its not.. Its a script provided as part of the Oracle EPM installation.